# dll in a different directory than c:\windows\system32

Tags: python, dll, windows-7, pylucene

Finally I managed to get pylucene working on my windows7 machine, 
Which raised a more general question:
How come that when I have a dll on a directory in the path, python couldn't find it,
and when I put the dll in c:\windows\system32 - it did work?

Using windows 7 32 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is probably, that if something like that happens to you, there is a wrong DLL somewhere in the path that is called first (and puttting the DLL in system32 ensures it is first).
So if you put the relevant DLL in your PATH - make sure it is the first (or look into each element to find out who is getting ahead of you)

Answered myself for future reference for people